# Migrate Javascript to CoffeeScript and make it work on page load

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, coffeescript

I am attempting to load a Javascript for a field's class. Here is my view:

```
<%= form_for @game do |f| %>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6">
      <div class="form-group">
        <%= f.label :time %>
        <%= f.text_field :time, class: 'form-control form-datetime', readonly: true %>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
<%= f.submit(class: 'btn btn-success')%>
<% end %>

<script>
  $(".form-datetime").datetimepicker({format: 'yyyy-mm-dd hh:ii'})
</script>
```

I can only get the Javascript to work on page refresh. On the first load, the page console states:

> Uncaught TypeError: $(...).datetimepicker is not a function

On page reload it works fine.

I have attempted to use the document ready handler as so, with no luck:

```
<script>
  $( document ).ready(function() {
    (".form-datetime").datetimepicker({format: 'yyyy-mm-dd hh:ii'});
  });
</script>
```

I have TurboLinks enabled so I tried this with no luck [How TurboLinks Works](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/working_with_javascript_in_rails.html#how-turbolinks-works):

```
$(document).on("page:change", function() {
  $(".form-datetime").datetimepicker({format: 'MM d, yyyy hh:iia'});
});
```

I would also like to remove this `<script>` tag from the view and place it in the CoffeeScript file. What do I need to write in the CoffeeScript file to load this Javascript function on first page load?

Comment: Try wrapping in *document.ready* handler. If your main scripts load below this in page then you are calling plugin before it has loaded and defined

Comment: updated, with no luck.

Comment: You are missing the jQuery sigil in your updated code:   `(".form-datetime").datetimepicker({...});` -- Probably a SO typo, though. Other than that, can you confirm that the function `datetimepicker` is indeed the correct name of the function?

Comment: It is a function, as it works when I do not use document ready and refresh the page. What do you mean 'missing the jQuery sigil'?

Comment: You don't have the dollar sign in the `$(document).ready(...)` code. Look at `(".form-datetime")`

Comment: attempted both ways as `(".form-datetime")` and `$(".form-datetime")`, with no luck.

Answer (score 0):

The CoffeeScript is:

```
$(document).ready -> $(".form-datetime").datetimepicker format: 'yyyy-mm-dd hh:ii'
```

Answer (score 0):

In your coffeescript file, use this to create the `loadDatePicker` function:

```
loadDatePicker ->
    $(".form-datetime").datetimepicker format: 'MM d, yyyy hh:iia'
```

This will make the function available for use from the page.

In your page HTML, use this script to load the DatePicker on specific events:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(loadDatePicker);

    // TurboLinks 5 events (only register if using TurboLinks 5
    jQuery(document).on('turbolinks:load', loadDatePicker);

    // TurboLinks Classic events (only register if using TurboLinks Classic
    // jQuery(document).on('page:load', loadDatePicker);
    // jQuery(document).on('page:change', loadDatePicker);
    // jQuery(document).on('page:restore', loadDatePicker);
</script>
```

These events cause the `loadDatePicker` method to be called under various turbolinks page load / update scenarios.  You may choose to add support for other TurboLinks events, depending on your application's needs.  The full list of events can be found on the [TurboLinks Full List of Events](https://github.com/turbolinks/turbolinks#user-content-full-list-of-events) or the [TurboLinks Classic Events](https://github.com/turbolinks/turbolinks-classic#user-content-events) pages.